# Is there a limit for sending emails with workflow?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I got a very big workflow system and there are many if/else blocks.And sending many auto emails. but now i cannot change the workflow. My workflow is simple but the hardest way. There are 50 conditions and it is sending 700 users. Is it the limit?

```
   if(condition 1)
      Action 1
      else if(condition 2)
      Action 2
      else if(condition 3)
      Action 3
      else if(condition 4)
      Action 4
      else
      Action 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if the workflow gets too long for your configuration it will give an error when you try to publish it. As long as it gets published it should be ok.